# How can I remove all whitespace and carriage returns from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string which is returning this to me:

```
<div class=\"sqs-layout sqs-grid-12 columns-12\" data-layout-label=\"Post Body\" data-type=\"item\" data-updated-on=\"1539277027193\" id=\"item-5bbf7e3f9140b70d3962e2a0\"><div class=\"row sqs-row\"><div class=\"col sqs-col-12 span-12\"><div class=\"sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image\" data-block-type=\"5\" id=\"block-yui_3_17_2_1_1539794362468_25479\"><div class=\"sqs-block-content\">\n\n  \n\n  \t\n      <div class=\"image-block-outer-wrapper">
```

Any idea how I can remove all the whitespaces and put this into a JS variable? I have tried countless variations of this:

```
.replace(/[\n\t\r]/g,"")
```

but nothing working yet...

Comment: Why does it matter, purily out of curiousity? Can't you just change the source of the data, instead of fighting the symptoms?

Comment: Try \s for whitespace.

Comment: @Icepickle it's Squarespace so can't do anything about the data output...

Comment: Did you check trim function of lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#trim

Comment: @Bernhard no luck I'm afraid

Comment: @AhmetTanakol Yes I've tried trim...

Comment: @Liam I have tried like this `.replace(/[\n\t\r\s]/g,"")` but that didn't work and `\s` alone didn't work either.

Comment: Note a carriage return, is not white space. It's an asci character that tells the rendering engine to put a newline in.

Comment: @Liam how can I strip a carriage return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183784/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-liam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the value after the replace to another variable or the same variable. This is because strings are immutable. Also add \s on the regex pattern.

```
var a = "\n\n  \n\n  \t\n      "
var b = a.replace(/[\n\t\r\s]/g, '');

//now b = "" and a still is "\n\n  \n\n  \t\n      "
a = a.replace(/[\n\t\r\s]/g, '');  // this also work
```